# aws route53 A record

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

i have a  question on what policy would apply for the following setup of a domain entry in Route53 DNS .

i have a domain , with an api subdomain pointing to 2 A records

```
api.xyz.com IN A 10.0.0.1 # (weighted routing policy)weight 100/region virgina

api.xyz.com IN A 10.0.0.2 # (weighted routing policy ) weight 0 /region virginia

api.xyz.com IN A 10.0.0.3 # (weighted routing policy) weight 100/region california

api.xyz.com IN A 10.0.0.4 # (weighted routing policy) weight 0 /region california
```

Now if a user resolves the url api.xyz.com , what chances are that the returning ip would be following a round robin method ? 
ie each query will query b/w 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.3 ?

---

On testing the results returned are random , out of 10 tries(dns lookup without cache)  i would get 10.0.0.1 - 3 times and 10.0.0.3 - 7 times. 
Querying the dns server(R53), there's no rule applied to give round robin results ( applied weighted method). 
So what governs this query returning different ip's ?

Comment: What are the TTL on those records? Based on TTL, the intermediate DNS server might cache the lookup.

Comment: default r53 at 300 sec ,
assuming the query without any cache what are the chances that it'll land up in any of the region's

Comment: If you query without cache, then it should work as per weight. If you have 300 seconds. The configurations says, you can cache the same IP for fiive minutes. So root DNS will not be called again until the cache expires.

Answer (score 0):

(To be honest I should include this as comment, but I don't have enough rep)

Theory dictates that your current setup should go 50/50, the actual rule being
[ **Weight of a Route / Weights of All Routes Combined** ]

The routes with weight of 0 will not be routed to.

The only "problem" I could see is that maybe your sample size is too small to determine if it's actually behaving as expected. Maybe try a few more queries to see if it stabilizes to 50% probability?